# Importing google api client libraries to python/flask

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to use python to authenticate Google id tokens for their oauth, as per their docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).  The code to do it seems manageable, but I am not too familiar with setting up libraries in the flask framework (or any python framework for that matter).

All I simply want is these lines to work:

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests
```

I have installed them with pip like:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

This on its own does not work.  But I saw these notes from Google on their docs:

> Because the Python client libraries are not installed in the App
>   Engine Python runtime environment, they must be [vendored into your](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring)
>   application just like third-party libraries.

It is trying to do this where I am lost.

I have added the file `appengine_config.py` as noted in their instuctions.  Although it says it needs to be in the same directory as a `app.yaml` file, which I do not have and do not see any information on how to set this up.

In short, am I on the correct path to install these google python libraries?  If so, what am I missing?  If not, what path should I be taking?

**EDIT**:  It turned out I was NOT using APP Engine, but Google's Docs made it seem like these were steps I needed to take which threw me off the correct (and more simplified) path.

Comment: You can refer to this link below for information related to creating the `app.yaml` file: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref

Comment: And this link as well: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don&#39;t understand what app engine is.  I simply want to use a small Google Library, do I have to set up all this other stuff up with it?  I literally have one route that needs this code.  Or is this the norm for python third party libraries?

Comment: Are you using app engine to run your python code or are you just trying to use the Google's oauth client library so that you can authenticate with Google? If it's the latter case, then I don't think you have to do all these app engine stuff.

Comment: @bharath  Yes, exactly that (your last comment).

Comment: See my answer below. That'll solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be because you're not using `virtualenv`. Just follow the instructions below and it'll work.

1. Install virtualenv using the instructions in this link below and once installed activate it using the `source /path/to/your/virtualenv` command:

https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#installing_and_using_virtualenv

2. Once you're inside your `vritualenv` follow the instructions in the link below to install the required google oauth libraries:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app

3. Now you can follow the below link for API reference or the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) you provided:

https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

Tested the above steps locally using `ipython` and it's working. Below is the output for the same.

```
In [1]: from google.oauth2 import id_token

In [2]: dir(id_token)
Out[2]: 
['_GOOGLE_APIS_CERTS_URL',
 '_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CERTS_URL',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '_fetch_certs',
 'exceptions',
 'http_client',
 'json',
 'jwt',
 'verify_firebase_token',
 'verify_oauth2_token',
 'verify_token']

In [3]: from google.auth.transport import requests

In [4]: dir(requests)
Out[4]: 
['AuthorizedSession',
 'Request',
 '_LOGGER',
 '_Response',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'absolute_import',
 'exceptions',
 'functools',
 'logging',
 'requests',
 'six',
 'transport']

In [5]:
```

`

Comment: Thanks, I do have virtualenv installed but perhaps not using it correctly.  Let me take a look at this solution.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked like a champ.   I had no idea you use the virtualnv this way.  I am obviously new to flask and python.

Comment: You're welcome. It's always a good practice to isolate your project dependencies using `virtualenv` in python. And don't forget to add the dependencies of your project to `requirements.txt` file so that you can lock your dependencies to specific version.